# How to pause a thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, bitmap, delphi-xe7

I want to draw something. Because the GUI freezes I want to draw in a thread. But sometimes I want to pause the drawing (for minutes).

Delphi's documentation says that Suspend/resume are obsolete but doesn't tell which functions replaces them.

Suspend and Resume are deprecated. [Sleep](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TThread.Sleep) and SpinWait are obviously inappropriate. I am amazed to see that Delphi does not offer such a basic property/feature.

So, how do I pause/resume a thread?

Comment: You set a flag which your thread checks regularly. It then draws, or does not draw, depending on the value of the flag.

Comment: Use an event and `WaitForSingleObject`...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - ok. and what do I use to pause the thread when the flag is 'DoNotDraw' ? THread.Sleep(100) is a good idea??

Comment: Nope. Sleeping is pretty much always a bad idea. You could wait for an event instead. Do that instead of a simple flag. So in your drawing loop wait for the event to be signaled. In the main thread, reset the event when you want to suspend drawing. Set it again when you want drawing to resume.

Comment: @whosrdaddy - Just a note :) While searching for WaitForSingleObject documentation I have found this: https://marc.durdin.net/2012/08/waitforsingleobject-why-you-should-never-use-it/

Comment: You do what we have already said. Wait on an event.

Comment: Using `WaitForSingleObject` is fine, if you do so correctly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may need `fPaused/fEvent` protection via a critical section. It depends on your concrete implementation.

```
interface

uses
  Classes, SyncObjs;

type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    fEvent: TEvent;
    fPaused: Boolean;
    procedure SetPaused(const Value: Boolean);
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const aPaused: Boolean = false);
    destructor Destroy; override;

    property Paused: Boolean read fPaused write SetPaused;
  end;

implementation

constructor TMyThread.Create(const aPaused: Boolean = false);
begin
  fPaused := aPaused;
  fEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, true, not fPaused, '');
  inherited Create(false);
end;

destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
begin
  Terminate;
  fEvent.SetEvent;
  WaitFor;
  fEvent.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    fEvent.WaitFor(INFINITE);
    // todo: your drawings here
  end;
end;

procedure TMyThread.SetPaused(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  if (not Terminated) and (fPaused <> Value) then
  begin
    fPaused := Value;
    if fPaused then
      fEvent.ResetEvent else
      fEvent.SetEvent;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Should't the inherited of the constructor be at the beginning and not at the end of the code?

Comment: This is a common pattern learnt before Delphi 6 fixed the constructor for `TThread` to postpone the actual thread creation to `AfterConstruction`. It's not been necessary to write it as above since then.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Pardon my not knowing, but what of "as above" hasn't been necessary since D6?

Comment: @AlexJames Calling the inherited constructor at the end of the derived constructor